# Disallow certain urls from googlebots

Tags: googlebot, google-index

I have the following urls:

```
http://www.website.com/somethingawesome/?render=xml

http://www.website.com/somethingawesome/?render=json
```

What I want is to disallow google from indexing when the url has `?render=xml` or `?render=json` inside it. **This can be variable to any url.**

My thoughts are :

```
Disallow: /?render=xml
Disallow: /?render=json
```

Will this work though? Should I be concerned about the url portion too? How can I make this work?

Comment: Use the tester Google provided: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You will need the wildcard first:

```
Disallow: /*?render=xml
Disallow: /*?render=json
```